# Degrees of separation in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I would like to know how I can count the degrees of separation among nodes within a network. 
I have created a network with two breeds that spread virus through time.

```
to setup
create-people_inf 5 [set label "Infected"]
create-people_well 20 [set label "Good health"]
end
```

Then I added new nodes to the preexisting ones as follows:

```
  ask people_inf
  [ create-links-to other people_inf
    [set color red ]
    let this_turtle self
    ask people_well
    [
     if random-float 1 < 0.5
     [
        create-link-to this_turtle [set color green]
    ]
    ]
  ]
```

This is just a default network. My question would be on how I can count the degrees of separation between one selected node and another one, randomly chosen. I thought of adding a flag and consider a logical condition (`if connected?=true`), but I do not know to consider the nodes in between. My approach would give me only information on one node and its directed connections.

Any suggestion is more than welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Network (nw) extension, see documentation at https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html. From that, you can use the `nw:distance-to` for any turtle to find the number of hops to any specified turtle